# How to copy table from SQL Linked Server to SQL Server and maintain key constraints?

Tags: sql-server, db2, ssms, linked-server

I have an SQL Server installed on a local Windows 10 machine - I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to interact with it.

I also have a DB2 database hosted on an IBM i machine and I've created a Linked Server in SQL Server Management Studio to represent it. I can connect to the Linked Server and can query/pull data from it successfully.

I'm trying to copy particular tables from the Linked Server and insert them into a Database/Schema in the SQL Server - I can do this successfully but unfortunately, it appears that in the process of copying the table over, none of the constraints (particularly in my case, the key constraints) are maintained.

Is there a simple way to copy over tables from a Linked Server to SQL Server (in SQL Server Management Studio) while maintaining key constraints?

The following query is an example of what I'm using to copy the tables over (one-by-one):

```
SELECT * 
INTO SQLSCHEMA.SQLTABLE 
FROM LINKSERVER.LINKDATABASE.LINKSCHEMA.LINKTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use proper tool for it like [SSMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) is a tool designed to automate database migration to SQL Server from Microsoft Access, DB2, MySQL, Oracle, and SAP ASE.
>
> [Migrating DB2 Databases to SQL Server (DB2ToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/db2/migrating-db2-databases-to-sql-server-db2tosql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for DB2 is a comprehensive environment that helps you quickly migrate DB2 databases to SQL Server or Azure SQL DB. By using SSMA for DB2, you can review database objects and data, assess databases for migration, migrate database objects to SQL Server or Azure SQL DB, and then migrate data to SQL Server or Azure SQL DB. Note that you cannot migrate SYS and SYSTEM DB2 schemas.

Comment: Looking at the following link (under Prerequisites), it appears that Microsoft designed this tool for DB2 for LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows) and DB2 for z/OS - it makes no mention of supporting DB2 on IBM i. Do you know if it supports it? I've downloaded the tool and am trying to connect but am running into inscrutable errors.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/db2/installing-ssma-for-db2-client-db2tosql?view=sql-server-ver15